# Create local data binding variable inside *ngIf statement

Tags: angular

I would like to pass a value from a dropdown selection element. Everything was working fine until I introduced `*ngIf`.

It seems that the `*ngIf` is removing the `#deviceInfoName` variable from the DOM and so when I go to fetch the value it's undefined.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="deviceSelection | async; else deviceManual">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select #deviceInfoName matNativeControl id="apiReadType" placeholder="Device Select">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let device of devices | async" [value]="device.name">{{device.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #deviceManual>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput #deviceInfoName placeholder="Device" value="">
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
```

I expected the value to be pulled from `#deviceInfoName` but I'm getting `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.

Comment: You could try `[hidden]="deviceSelection"` instead of `*ngIf` which will not remove the element from DOM.

Comment: @AmitChigadani that will work. What happens when I have two dom elements with the same id active? I will have to test.

Comment: That may not work. Its better to have two different template references.

Comment: @AustenStone Both will work same but the main difference is that when you will use `*ngIf` , the element will be added to DOM only when condition of  `*ngIf` is true else it will be removed from DOM. On other hand, `[hidden]` uses display property of CSS to hide or show elements on html page. It does not remove element from DOM. if condition is true any time its load in a DOM `*ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

I can create two different templates so that the `(click)` is in the same scope as the variable. This is just a lot of redundant code.

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="deviceSelection | async; else deviceManual">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select #deviceInfoName matNativeControl id="apiReadType" placeholder="Device Select">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let device of devices | async" [value]="device.name">{{device.name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select #deviceInfoType matNativeControl id="apiwriteType" placeholder="Info Type">
        <mat-option value="1">Properties</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">Attributes</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="3" selected="">Variables</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="4">Structures</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">Commands</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">Map Descriptions</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">RT Status</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">Errors</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="deviceInfo(deviceInfoName.value, deviceInfoType.value)">Get Info</button>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #deviceManual>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput #deviceInfoName placeholder="Device" value="">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select #deviceInfoType matNativeControl id="apiwriteType" placeholder="Info Type">
        <mat-option value="1">Properties</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">Attributes</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="3" selected="">Variables</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="4">Structures</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">Commands</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">Map Descriptions</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">RT Status</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">Errors</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="deviceInfo(deviceInfoName.value, deviceInfoType.value)">Get Info</button>
  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```